# При подключении пропадает соединение через основной интерфейс

Tags: сеть, openvpn, маршрутизация, linux

Здравствуйте.
Есть локальная сеть с выходом в интеренет. В этой же сети Openvpn сервер. VPN нужен для связи с одним единственным компьютером. При подключении к VPN пропадает связь с интеренетом и другими компьютерами в локальной сети. Как сделать возможность Одновременной работы в интернет и сервером в VPN. В сетях и маршрутизации мои позния довольно скромны.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Все правильно, по-умолчанию весь трафик направляется в VPN соединение.
Необходимо прописать маршруты для Вашей сети, VPN и интернета.
При прописывании маршрутов для ВПН следует знать, к каким ресурсам будете подключаться за ВПН-ом и прописать их на ВПН-интерфейс.
[Настройка маршрутизации в Ubuntu Linux, для начинающих](http://www.opennet.ru/base/net/ubuntu_route.txt.html)
[Маршрутизация в Linux](http://xgu.ru/wiki/%D0%9C%D0%B0%D1%80%D1%88%D1%80%D1%83%D1%82%D0%B8%D0%B7%D0%B0%D1%86%D0%B8%D1%8F_%D0%B2_Linux)
и т.п. в гугле...

Answer (score 1):

Уберите из конфига openvpn опцию про push default route (не помню как оно там точно называется). В настройках vpn-клиента проверьте, что нет галки вида "использовать это соединение для всех адресов/подключений/etc" или соответствующей строчки в конфиге, если ovpn консольный.